# Invalid Python expression when using driver with Python script

Tags: python, scripting, drivers, error

I'm trying to use a python script as an expression in a driver. It was working fine at first and then all of a sudden I get the error message *ERROR: Invalid Python expression*.

[image: ERROR: Invalid Python Expression]

I've tried running the script in the text editor multiple times with no errors, but I get an error in the driver section. Anyone know how to solve this?

Scrip in text

```
import bpy

prevTime = 0

###
# Rotates the object with the rotSpeed value in radians/s
###
def rotate(rotSpeed, curRot):
    scn = bpy.context.scene
    curFrame = scn.frame_current
    fps = scn.render.fps

    # Calculate total playtime
    time = curFrame / fps

    # Get delta time
    dt = time - prevTime

    # This will set the current rotation value of the object!!
    newRot = curRot + rotSpeed * dt

    # Set new previous time
    prevTime = time

    return newRot


# Add to driver namaespece to make it accessable     
bpy.app.driver_namespace['RotWithSpeed'] = rotate
```

EDIT: The error occurs when I add the line "prevTime = time".

Comment: It looks ok.  (preferable if you post code as code rather than image to test)  Have you tried the "update dependencies" button?

Comment: Added the code as text in my question. Yes I've tried that, didn't make any difference.

Comment: You need to declare prevtime as a global. (although not sure you really need that anyhow since it (frame - 1) eqtn.    One issue is that jumps out now I look closer is that you are using the object property you are driving as an input to the driver as well, might cause issues too.

Comment: Isn't prevTime global by default when it's declared outside the function? I need the prevTime since it has to work in both directions in time. Tried to use something else as the input rather than the object property itself, the error stays. Also tried to remove the driver and then apply a new one, no difference.

Comment: The problem occurs on the line "prevTime = time". Global variables don't seem to work the same way in Blender as in raw Python. I Still don't know how to solve it though.

Comment: Did you put `global prevTime` in the rotate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after a while. Seems like global functions don't work the same way in Blender as in raw Python.

I used [mini3d's solution found on the blender forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20201030143235/https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27291).

Here's a summary of the solution:

```
import bpy

# Define global variables
bpy.types.Scene.prevTime = bpy.props.FloatProperty()

def getSettings():
    settings = bpy.data.scenes.get("Settings")
    if settings is None:
        settings = bpy.data.scenes.new("Settings")
    
    return settings

def rotate(rotSpeed, curRot):
    .
    .
    getSettings().prevTime = time
    .
    .
```

EDIT: Global variables do in fact work the same way. The following solution is much cleaner as suggested by [batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger)

The problem was that I tried to edit a global variable in a function without using the keyword "global".

```
import bpy

# Define global variables
prevTime = 0

def rotate(rotSpeed, curRot):
    # This will give us the ability to edit the global variable
    global prevTime  
    .
    .
```

Comment: Disagree, globals work the same in blender.  Example set up a driver with `x(0, 1)` as a driver expression ( using http://pasteall.org/210634/python ).  Every time the driver is called the global variable c is updated, and will be by any prop that has `f(..)` as a driver expression.

Comment: No idea why that didn't work when I tried it previously. Your solution is much cleaner. Will update the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to occur whenever the driver's function raises an exception. It's a shame the error message doesn't contain the stack trace. In your case I think batFINGER is right: `prevTime` is being *written to* as a global, so it must be declared at the top of the function as `global prevTime`. Variables that you only read from don't need to be declared as global.